# Create a website and stay anonymous

Tags: anonymity

I am a newbie. I learned `mysql` and `PHP` and created a website ... in `localhost`. Finally my website is ready and I am going to buy a server.

However I want to stay anonymous so that nobody will know this website is created by me. How i can be an anonymous website owner.

**AN EXAMPLE:** Satoshi Nakomoto created bitcoin and stayed anonymous. If i want to look for the owner of bitcoin.org I cant find it.

Comment: I recommend editing your question to remove the speculation without backing "I mean its very clear bitcoin is a CIA job". Very much detracts from the discussion.

Comment: i was sure this sentence will return to me as a downvote, but if you look closely you will see even bitcoin owners says that.I am a bitcoin user and on bitcointalk.org people always debate on that issue. I will leave this opinion here as an "opinion"  nothing else ----haha it got edited

Comment: If I ping bitcoin.org, I find the IP address is 208.64.123.130, which is registered to something called Black Lotus Communications and served by Hurricane Electric.  "whois bitcoin.org" tells me it's registered through WhoisGuard.  In other words, the operators of bitcoin.org did just what I've suggested.  If I have a gold badge, I can find out who's paying WhoisGuard and Hurricane Electric.  I might be able to find out through bribery, coercion, social engineering, or just "knowing someone."

Comment: @BobBrown As a newbie i sould ask. so if i use WhoisGuard it will be enough to hide from "people". I already know goverment can find me if he wants.

Comment: @WebberDepor Comments are not for extended discussion.  Please do some research.  You can find "private domain registration" and "WhoisGuard" with Google.

Comment: Satoshi didn't create bitcoin.org. He posted a paper and some software on sourceforge.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, at least not completely.  Your web site will have an IP address, and that IP address will be associated with you.  Unless people access the site only by IP, you will have a domain name associated with you.

You can make it difficult for most people, what you call normal people, to find your identity by using a hosting service rather than buying a server and using a "private registration" service for your domain name.  The IP address will track back to the hosting service and the domain name will track back to the registration service.

*However,* if what you're doing attracts the attention of law enforcement, your identity can be uncovered by subpoena or other legal process.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the short and quick answer to this, but I believe this is what you're looking for:

[Configuring Hidden Services for Tor](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en)

Comment: Can you explain further?

Comment: @SourLolita There's really nothing to explain. It's all in the link. If the OP needs any more information, then this unfortunately isn't the resource to help with that. Is that the reason for the downvote? Just because an answer is short doesn't mean it's unhelpful...

Comment: It won't be as helpful in the future to others if the link is no longer available, whether it's moved or removed.

Comment: @SourLolita That's not true at all. The name of the link, "Configuring Hidden Services for Tor", will still be there, and a quick search of the text on any search engine would yield satisfactory results.

Comment: So after someone arrives at this page through a google search, you would like them to continue to search for an article that may potentially not exist anymore, rather than outline what it contains?

Comment: @SourLolita If I were searching for a way to host a website anonymously and stumbled across this page and the link didn't work, I would certainly not just dismiss it as an answer. I would continue on with this newly acquired information and use it to my benefit when narrowing down what I want to actually find. In which case, this answer is actually valuable. So I don't see what your issue is with it, if you have a legitimate issue that is.